# How do I figure out the signatories addresses from a multisig address?

Tags: multisig

Does `polkadot.js` provide a method to determine the addresses of signatories associated with a particular multisig address?

Answer (score 2):

Nope, it's a one way hash.

You can't get the signatories from just a multisig address.

---

And in PolkadotApps you need to add signatories to the address book and pass the threshold to recover the multisig account, then you can use the multisig features.